# Can I upload multiple image to browser and zip it to one file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, zip

As the title, can I do that? upload multiple images to the browser and zip it to one file using Javascript

please I'm not expecting the answer of code, just wanna know is this possible to do that, could anyone please give me some hints or direction, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one js library that can solve your problem.

here is the link http://stuk.github.io/jszip/

```
function upload(files){

    var zip = new JSZip();                       
    let archive = zip.folder("test");

    files.map(function(file){
        files.file(file.name, file.raw, {base64: true});
    }.bind(this));

    return archive.generateAsync({
        type: "blob",
        compression: "DEFLATE",
        compressionOptions: {
           level: 6
        }
    }).then(function(content){ 
        // here you will get the zipped file, so you can pass this file to the server
    });
}
```